# How big are Premier Inn Hub "Bigger" rooms?

Tags: hotels, london, accommodation

What is the square footage of a Westminster (London) [Premier Inn Hub "Bigger" room](https://www.hubhotels.co.uk/london/westminster-st-james-park.html/)? None of the hotel's online information answers this question, and all of the references I can find online describe only the regular room.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70666/discussion-on-question-by-orome-how-big-are-premier-inn-hub-bigger-rooms).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the hotel, the size of Bigger room is 13 m<sup>2</sup> (140 ft<sup>2</sup>) and Standard room 11 m<sup>2</sup> (118 ft<sup>2</sup>).